# What should be done to fit a webview to the device screen size in wp8.1?

Tags: webview, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing an application in WP 8.1 which uses the webview control. I tested the app in a 4 inch device and looked fine. but when this app was tested in a bigger device the web view doesn't seem to fit the screen. My xaml code is like

```
<Grid Margin="0,0.333,0,-1.333" Height="641" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ProgressBar x:Name="home_progress_bar" IsIndeterminate="True" Visibility="Collapsed" Height="70" Margin="0,282,2,258" Canvas.ZIndex="999999" FontSize="15"/>
    <WebView x:Name="orderWebView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" ScriptNotify="orderWebView_ScriptNotify" NavigationStarting="orderWebView_navigation_starting" NavigationFailed="orderWebView_navigation_failed" NavigationCompleted="orderWebView_NavigationCompleted" Height="643" Width="400" DOMContentLoaded="orderWebView_DOMContentLoaded" Margin="0,0,0,-2"/>
</Grid>
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar x:Name="Appbar_homepage" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" ClosedDisplayMode="Minimal" >
        <AppBarButton x:Name="AppButton_home" Label="home" Icon="Home" Click="AppButton_home_Click"/>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Please point out what I am missing.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have hardcoded the width and height of the WebView. Remove the Width and Height properties, change HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment to "Stretch" and optionally play with the Margin property to give it a bit of a margin around.
Example:

```
<WebView x:Name="orderWebView" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" />
```